# Jest mock not resolving to each injected value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to test a Firebase cloud function named `myCloudFn` in my `functions/send.js` module. My tests are in `functions/test/send.spec.js`:

```js
// send.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

async function myCloudFn (email) {
  const authUser = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
  return authUser;
}

module.exports = { myCloudFn };
```

```js
// send.spec.js
const send = require('../send.js');

jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  auth: () => ({
    getUserByEmail: jest.fn()
      .mockResolvedValueOnce({ uid: 'foo-bar' })
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(null),
  }),
}));

describe('send.js', () => {
  it('returns authUser from myCloudFn()', async () => {
    const email = 'foo@bar.com';
    const responseOptions = [{ uid: 'foo-bar' }, null];
    const responsePromises = responseOptions.map(() => send.myCloudFn(email));
    const responses = await Promise.all(responsePromises);
    expect(responses[0]).toStrictEqual(responseOptions[0]);
    expect(responses[1]).toStrictEqual(responseOptions[1]);
  });
});
```

The test passes on the first assertion, but fails on the second. The test returns the same `{ uid: 'foo-bar' }` object both times, but I want the test response value to be `null` the second time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new `getUserByEmail` spy is created on each `auth` call, it isn't called more than once.

Instead, it should be:

```
const mockGetUserByEmail = jest.fn();
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  auth: () => ({
    getUserByEmail: mockGetUserByEmail
  })
}));

...
mockGetUserByEmail
  .mockResolvedValueOnce({ uid: 'foo-bar' })
  .mockResolvedValueOnce(null);
const responsePromises = responseOptions.map(() => send.myCloudFn(email));
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood how the `once`-type methods worked. This resolved my issue nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the resolved value once of the `getUserByEmail` method for each test case.

E.g.

`send.js`:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

async function myCloudFn(email) {
  const authUser = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
  return authUser;
}

module.exports = { myCloudFn };
```

`send.test.js`:

```js
const { myCloudFn } = require('./send');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

jest.mock(
  'firebase-admin',
  () => {
    const mAdmin = {
      auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      getUserByEmail: jest.fn(),
    };
    return mAdmin;
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('send.js', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should returns authUser from myCloudFn()', async () => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail.mockResolvedValueOnce({ uid: 'foo-bar' });
    const actual = await myCloudFn();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ uid: 'foo-bar' });
  });
  it('should return null', async () => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail.mockResolvedValueOnce(null);
    const actual = await myCloudFn();
    expect(actual).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64575307/send.test.js (14.349s)
  send.js
    ✓ should returns authUser from myCloudFn() (11ms)
    ✓ should return null (3ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 send.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.321s
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the accepted answer for my code, but this is a really nicely composed response. It made me reason harder about the mocks, which I found helpful.