# Jest mock not allowing inner function to be resolved in individual test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm testing a cloud function named `myCloudFn` in my `functions/send.js` module. My tests are in `functions/test/send.test.js`:

```js
// send.js
const { getCompareDate } = require('../utils.js');

async function myCloudFn(myTestDate) {
  const compareDate = await getCompareDate(argToTest);
  const isOlder = myTestDate < compareDate;
  return isOlder ? 'older' : 'newer';
}

module.exports = { myCloudFn };
```

```js
// send.test.js
const send = require('../send.js');

jest.mock('../utils', () => ({
  getCompareDate: jest.fn(() => new Date('2020-01-31')) // default
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-04-04'))
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-02-02')),
}));

describe('send.js', () => {
  it('returns date comparison from myCloudFn()', async () => {
    const myTestDate = '2020-03-03';
    const returnValues = ['older', 'newer'];
    const responsePromises = returnValues.map(() => send.myCloudFn(myTestDate));
    const responses = await Promise.all(responsePromises);
    expect(responses[0]).toBe(returnValues[0]);
    expect(responses[1]).toBe(returnValues[1]);
  });
});
```

The test functions correctly and passes as expected when I mock `getCompareDate` in this way, but for flexibility, I would rather provide custom input values for `getCompareDate` inside my tests and not 'globally'. Here's what I've tried:

```js
const mockGetCompareDate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../utils', () => ({
  getCompareDate: mockGetCompareDate,
}));
```

```js
  it('returns date comparison from myCloudFn()', async () => {
    mockGetCompareDate
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-04-04'))
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-02-02'));

    const myTestDate = '2020-03-03';
    const returnValues = ['older', 'newer'];
    const responsePromises = returnValues.map(() => send.myCloudFn(myTestDate));
    const responses = await Promise.all(responsePromises);
    expect(responses[0]).toBe(returnValues[0]);
    expect(responses[1]).toBe(returnValues[1]);
  });
```

This method, however, is not working and throws an error:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockGetCompareDate' before initialization`
I've used this method with other tests as noted in the solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64581024/2580754), but I am not seeing similar results here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest is hoisting the mocked function to the top of the module, and hence throws this error. The mock should instead be used right before you run the test. [Further reading](https://medium.com/@ericdcobb/advanced-react-component-mocks-with-jest-and-react-testing-library-f1ae8838400b).

Try this:

```
const { getCompareDate } = require('../utils.js');

const mockGetCompareDate = jest.fn(() => new Date('2020-01-31'));

jest.mock('../utils.js', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  getCompareDate: jest.fn(),
  default: jest.fn()
}));

beforeAll(() => {
  getCompareDate.mockImplementation(mockGetCompareDate);
});
```

To provide custom values do as you did before, when initialising the mock function. [Source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations)

Like this:

```
const mockGetCompareDate = jest.fn()
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-04-04'))
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-02-02'));
```

Or do as you did before inside the test. [Source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values)

Like this:

```
it('returns date comparison from myCloudFn()', async () => {
    mockGetCompareDate
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-04-04'))
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(new Date('2020-02-02'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I provide custom input values for `getCompareDate` inside my tests?

Comment: That helps, thanks. All good now. I had to make two changes to get it working: 1) changed `namedExport` to `getCompareDate`, and 2) edit the `mockGetCompareDate` definition to be `jest.fn(() => new Date('2020-01-31'));` The former errors if not present; the latter restores default value functionality if I don't provide something specific in my test.

Comment: That's great, glad it helped. And thanks as well for the update. Learnt something new.